# Parsing data from a text file into multiple arrays, and creating a payroll code from it

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, text

•   Creating a payroll file
    
•   A payroll file contains hourly pay information of 20 employees in two department, human resources and police department.  The file will have two columns of floating-point numbers. The first column is for human resources and the second column for police department. So each row has two floating-point numbers. 
    
•   You will need to create a payroll file by using random numbers in [0, 100) as double types.
    
•   Reading the payroll file.
    
•   You need to use nextLine() of a Scanner object to read each line from the payroll file.
    
•   Parse each line to get an array of two hourly pays by using splitString() function that we discussed in the class. The function will return String [] type.  The functions of String and Character class will be a help to solve splitString. 
    
•   Compute total pay and average pay for each department 
    
•   You will need to use Double.parseDouble() to convert pay of String type to a double type
    
•   Write an output file with total pays and average pays.
    
•   Use “pay.txt” for the input file name and “summary.txt” for the output file name.

Now I understand how to do this without the arrays, as I have finished that. But once I am supposed to parse the txt file into multiple arrays I am completely lost. My professor is prohibiting us from using in.hasNextDouble(), which is how I solved the last program. How do I separate the two numbers on the same line in the txt files in the program into two different arrays without it?

Here is the code from the last program, and where I am currently with the current one.

```
public class FileHandling {
public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File inputFileName = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFileName);


    double averageWorker = 0;
    double averageHr = 0;

    double totalWorkerPay = 0;
    System.out.println("    HR\t\tWorkers");
    double totalHrPay = 0;
    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        double humanResourcesPay = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%8.3f\t", humanResourcesPay);
        totalHrPay += humanResourcesPay;



        double workerPay = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%.3f\n", workerPay);
        totalWorkerPay += workerPay;


        averageWorker = totalWorkerPay/3;
        averageHr = totalHrPay/3;


    }
    System.out.printf("Total pay for HR is %.1f", totalHrPay);
    System.out.printf("\nAverage pay for HR is %.1f", averageHr);
    System.out.printf("\nThe total pay for Workers is %.1f", totalWorkerPay);
    System.out.printf("\nAverage pay for Workers is %.1f", averageWorker);


    System.out.print("\nEnter the file name:");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String outputFileName = console.nextLine();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
    System.out.println("total is " + totalHrPay);

    in.close();
    out.close();

}






}
```

Okay and here is what I have so far on this homework.

```
public class FileHandlingNextLine {


public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File inputFileName = new File("pay.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFileName);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    double total[] = new double[2];
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Line : " + line);
        String pays[] = splitString(line);
        for(i = 0; i < pays.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf(pays[i]);     

        total[i] += Double.parseDouble(pays[i]);

    }
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am lost and my teacher is of little help.

Comment: You'll get more help if you post not only the current state of your code, but also your thought process.  What are you stuck on right now?  Which pieces do you have an idea how to solve and which ones are you stuck on (and what have you thought of so far for how to solve them)?  SO exists to help people learn as they try problems themselves and get stuck on things, but for anyone to help you you need to show your thinking about the problem and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: @Tim I know I need to put the string into a character array and parse the character array one by one and put the digits into two substrings. Sadly my professor doesn't give us much to work with in class, so most of it is learned outside the classroom. I'm just lost on this one.